# Factory pattern to "set" product in addition to "get" product?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

I am new to design patterns. I am looking for a pattern similar to the factory pattern but that will also let me "set" the product. Something like this:

```
class VehicleFactory
{
    IVehicle static GetVehicle();
    void static SetVehicle(IVehicle vehicle);
}
```

Is there any known pattern similar to this? Thank you.

EDIT: I am looking to store "POCO" objects in the Session object and use a class to set/ get them. I may want to switch persistance to ViewState/ database in the future. This is what I have:

```
// object to persist in Session.
class Vehicle
{
    string Make { get; set; }
    string Model { get; set; }
}

// class to set/ get object from Session.
// Please see VehicleFactory above.
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Why do you need this pattern?

Comment: Can you describe why you need the set-part? It feels like you are trying to solve a different problem

Comment: I added more info. Thank you for your help.

Comment: With Session do you mean some kind of web session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factory pattern is a **creational design pattern** with encapsulates the creation of a complex object and isolates the creation process from your business logic.

Here it looks like you want a **cache** to store and manage the Vehicle instances. I would recommend that you call this class a **VehicleCache** rather than Factory and implement like a cache.

Firstly you should consider having and identifier for the Vehicle object like a vehicleId. I would also recommend that you implement it as an [entity object](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/109) as described in [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

Then you can implement your cache like this -

```
public class VehicleCache
{
    public void Add(IVehicle instanceToAdd)
    {
    // Store instance in session object
    }

    public IVehicle Get(string id) 
    {
     // search and return vehicle from cache
    }

    // more methods and indexer if required
}
```

Here are some links that explain how you can implement such cache for your application in a thread safe fashion -

https://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/frankb/archive/2008/12/31/Implementing-a-Thread-Safe-cache-using-the-Parallel-Extensions.aspx

http://www.objectreference.net/post/Implementing-Generic-Caching.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Also if you are new to Design Patterns you should consider reading Head First Design Patterns - http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126

Answer (score 1):

Like Unmesh says, the name is kind of misleading. 
You simply want to cache IVehicle object.

```
IVehicleCache
{
  IVehicle GetVehicle();
  void SetVehicle(IVehicle vehicle);
}

// Implementation for http session

public class HttpSessionVehicleCache : IVehicleCache
{
  public IVehicle GetVehicle()
  {
    return (IVehicle)HttpContext.Current.Session["Vehicle"];
  }

  void SetVehicle(IVehicle vehicle)
  {
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Vehicle"] = vehicle;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Marcus that was helpful too.